# How do I use a generic type projection in a method parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, types, projection

I have case classes and for each case class T I define an Entity[T] implicit. These instances define an Id type that is specific to each T. I then define an abstract Table[T] class with a retrieve method that takes an identifier of the Id type defined in T through a type projection...

But it does not work, I get type mismatches:

```
scalac generic-type-projection.scala
generic-type-projection.scala:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : id.type (with underlying type Entity[T]#Id)
 required: _5.Id where val _5: Entity[T]
        val key = implicitly[Entity[T]].keyFromId(id)  // Type mismatch on 'id'.
                                              ^
generic-type-projection.scala:41: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("dummy")
 required: Entity[A]#Id
    t.retrieve("dummy")
           ^
two errors found
```

Here's the code:

```scala
import java.util.UUID

trait Entity[T] {
  type Id
  type Key
  def getId(entity: T): Id
  def keyFromId(id: Id): Key
}

case class A(f1: String, f2: Int)

object AImplicits {
  implicit object AEntity extends Entity[A] {
    type Id = String
    type Key = UUID
    def getId(entity: A) = entity.f1
    def keyFromId(id: String) = UUID.fromString(id)
  }
}

object Main {
  abstract class Table[T: Entity] {
    def store(entity: T): Unit
    def retrieve(id: Entity[T]#Id): Option[T]
  }

  def makeTable[T: Entity]: Table[T] =
    new Table[T] {
      def store(entity: T): Unit = {}
      def retrieve(id: Entity[T]#Id): Option[T] = {
        val key = implicitly[Entity[T]].keyFromId(id)  // Type mismatch on 'id'.
        None
      }
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import AImplicits._
    val t = makeTable[A]
    val a = A("dummy", 9)
    t.store(a)
    t.retrieve("dummy")  // Type mismatch on "dummy".
  }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what is `E` in `def store(entity: E): Unit`

Comment: Sorry, that was a mixup. There should be no Es, only Ts. I edited the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type mismatch is a bit easier to see when you expand the context bound shorthand. Remember, the `[T : Entity]` syntax is just syntactic sugar for requiring an implicit `Entity[T]` to be in scope. So the header of your `makeTable` function is actually:

```
def makeTable[T](implicit entity: Entity[T]): Table[T] =
```

Now with that implicit parameter in scope, your `implicitly` call in the function will grab that value (actually, the `new Table[T]` constructor grabs the implicit, and then `implicitly` grabs it from there), so the `makeTable` function in its expanded form:

```
def makeTable[T](implicit entity: Entity[T]): Table[T] =
  new Table[T] {
    def store(entity: T): Unit = {}
    def retrieve(id: Entity[T]#Id): Option[T] = {
      val key = entity.keyFromId(id)  // Type mismatch on 'id'.
      None
    }
  }
```

Notice that there is no conversion taking place for the type declaration of the `id` parameter of `retrieve`. Essentially, the compiler is complaining that `entity.keyFromId` is expecting a parameter of type `entity.Id`, but your `id` parameter is of the abstract type `Entity[T]#Id`.

The problem here is that you want to hide the `Entity` and the ids from users of the `Table` class, yet you want to expose the type of the `Id` in one of the methods. Suppose I have two instances of `Table[T]`, but they use different `Entity[T]` implementations -- so different that their `Id` types are actually different. How would the users of the table instances know which type to pass to `retrieve` functions? You could fix this by adding another type parameter to the `Table` class. You can still abstract away the id/key generation logic, but this will allow the compiler to type check to make sure the `retrieve` function is getting the right type of parameter.

Comment: You're right about it being a path-dependent type problem. My question was poorly formulated as I was actually looking for a solution to make the implicit parameter's type to match the abstract type (in the type projection)... I finally found a way by using an early initializer with an abstract val set to the implicit object.  Accepting your reply as the answer.